# Facebook messages on my email account

Tags: facebook

My Facebook messages are entering on my email account as well, I tried to delete email address from my Facebook account but I am having a problem. How can I block Facebook messages from coming to my email account?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom-left corner, click **Block** App. **Email notifications** are **Facebook** updates that you receive via **email**. To adjust your **email notifications** from **Facebook**: Click at the top-right corner and select Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete your email address from your Facebook account. It helps you to recover your account and make it secure.

You can adjust your email notifications. Email notifications are Facebook updates that you receive via email.

[To adjust your email notifications from Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/154884887910599):

> 1. Click v *symbol* at the top-right corner and select **Settings**.
> 2. Click **Notifications** on the left.
> 3. Select **Email**.
> 4. From here, you can adjust your email notifications.

You can unsubscribe that particular notification from your email also by clicking on unsubscribe at the end of the email.